# Aws amplify auth hub listener doesnt detect login on production url

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I set up amplify federated auth via cognito on my webpage in react

Attaching a video to explain the problem

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oyNPjdCtshVXgqyfW6hqgvcz5oWrlRei/view

Basically on localhost, it works as expected
but on production the Hub doesnt detect login

I tried to debug this and im pulling my hair now :/ Any help is appreciated!

The listener i have is this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      console.log(event)
      switch (event) {
        case 'signIn':
        case 'cognitoHostedUI':
          getUser()
          break;
        case 'signOut':
          setUser(null);
          break;
        case 'signIn_failure':
        case 'cognitoHostedUI_failure':
          console.log('Sign in failure', data);
          break;
      }
    });
 }, []);

//get user function

function getUser() {
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(userData => {userData
      console.log(userData)
        setUser(userData)
        const btn = document.getElementById('login-account')
        btn.innerHTML = userData.attributes.email;
      })
      .catch(() => console.log('Not signed in'));
  }
```

This is the repo - https://github.com/ananddharne/milind-academy

When i check in the dashboard for amplify i actually see the user signed up

Comment: Check the message included in payload.data. There's some additional information that might be helpful. Also and this might not have anything to do with it but you're missing the array of dependencies at the end of your useEffect.

Comment: it doesnt even reach the log statement @Mickers

Comment: yes!, i have it configured correctly, edited it here, thanks!